# django: need to modify view in installed package

Tags: python, django

I am using ckeditor in my django project.
I did some code customizing in the view of the package (in ckeditor_uploader).

If I deploy now to the production server I need to include the changes that I did in the package (located in lib/site-packages...).

What would be a good way?

I am seeing only this option:
a) use an editor to modify the installed package on the production server.

Are there any other option that allow me to keep the changed code in my actual project (that is stored and deployed via github) ?

Comment: No, you should never modify third party packages. If you do that, you can not upgrade without breaking functionality. Can you be more elaborate on what you are looking to achieve? May be there are configurable options to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately its not configurable, and there are no classes involved. Its a simple view in the package and I added some lines of code: changed sorting, added a date for a file to be shown, etc...

Comment: so if its only a simple views than why do you need it install as a package? Just copy & paste & modify and that its

Answer (score 2):

It won't do you any good modifying the package.  Instead, you should subclass the view and override the methods you need to behave differently.

```
from ckeditor_uploader import ImageUploadView

class MyCustomView(ImageUploadView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        # do something different here,
        # then hand things over to 
        # the original parent
        return super(MyCustomView, self).post(request, **kwargs)
```